# flutter AnimatedPositioned cause a Ui jank

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using AnimatedPositioned to make animation.

```
   Obx(() {
      return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: controller.animationController,
        builder: (context, child) =>
            AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
              bottom: controller.actionsBottom,
              child: child!,
            ),
        child:
          !controller.trloaded.value
              ? const SizedBox()
              : Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  GlobalButton(
                    title: controller.trLanding('signUp'),
                    type: ButtonType.outlinedPrimary,
                    width: 154.w,
                    height: 56,
                    onTap: () => controller.goToSignUp(),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20.w),
                  GlobalButton(
                      borderWidth: 1,
                      borderColor: AppColors.primary[800]!,
                      title: controller.trLanding("signIn"),
                      width: 154.w,
                      height: 56,
                      onTap: () => controller.goToSignIn()),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "By Signing up you agree with our ",
                      style: textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                        color: AppColors.neutral[400],
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        // clearData();
                        push(TermsPage());
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Terms and Conditions",
                        style: textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                          color: AppColors.primary[700],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

      );
    }),
```

When I run the app by profile mode I got these problems:
[image]

To fix that I am using Animation Builder and I added my widgets to its child but I have the above problem. How can I fix that?

Comment: if you use `AnimatedBuilder` there is no need for `AnimatedPositioned` - simply use `Positioned`

Comment: It is better but I still have a jank https://pasteboard.co/6IYOFmVHcixF.png @pskink

Comment: so try to remove `AnimatedBuilder` and use only `AnimatedPositioned` (but honestly i doubt if it makes big difference)

Comment: or alternatively remove both `AnimatedBuilder` and `AnimatedPositioned` and replace them with `CustomSingleChildLayout` and pass `controller.animationController` as a `relayout` parameter to delegate [constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/SingleChildLayoutDelegate/SingleChildLayoutDelegate.html)

Comment: I used AnimatedPositioned and like animated builder I have jank. Ok let me try CustomSingleChildLayout @pskink

Comment: What I have to put inside `shouldRelayout` ? https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/k8NKbMDmww/ @pskink

Comment: whatever: `true` or `false` - but of course you have to override `getConstraintsForChild` and 
`getPositionForChild` methods (or at least `getPositionForChild` to position the child according to your `animationController` current value)

Comment: If I want to be honest, It results with AnimatedBuilder + positioned is no difference  https://pasteboard.co/Ys127R9rvJ7h.png @pskink

Comment: post your code then

Comment: This is my animation ctl https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7wY2yKcbTh/ and my CustomLayoutDelegate https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jXmYMZVQk8/ and mu usage https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3mnZ6Cqn3q/  @pskink

Comment: Yes, you have  jank https://pasteboard.co/MzwXK7fdxspo.png @pskink

Comment: Yes,I measure in profile mode in Android studio and I am testing om my Samsung S31 @pskink

Comment: on Samsung a35  actully @pskink

Comment: sorry, `CustomSingleChildLayout` is the fastest way of animating layout as no widget building is performed during every frame... so if it is still slow then...